# Retain [None, None, None, x] input shape when using `tf.train.batch`

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a fully convolutional model which can take images of any input resolution using tensorflow 1.5.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
image, segmentation = \
    D.get_training_dataset_data_provider()

image, segmentation = \
    tf.train.batch([image, segmentation],
                    batch_size=16)

# Define the model:
predictions, loss, end_points = M.model_w_batch_norm(
    image,
    segmentation
            )
```

Then I go on to use a `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` to train the model. Everything works really nicely, except that I am getting a model that has an fixed input shape (i.e. `image_in` has the shape I am feeding from my dataset data provider).

The `get_training_dataset_data_provider` loads images from a tfrecord and augments them. The output is a constant resolution, which is fine for training. For testing / prediction, however I would like to be able to pass images of any shape.

The model itself is fully convolutional (in `M.model_w_batch_norm`) has the tensor `image_in` defined:

```
def model_w_batch_norm(in_image, trainable=True):
    in_image = tf.identity(in_image, name="image_in")
    ...
```

If I were not to use `tf.train.batch`, I would just define a `Placeholder` with shape (None, None, None, x), but I think I cannot link `tf.train.batch` to a placeholder, can I?

How do can I define an input tensor for the model of the shape `(None, None, None, x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution turns out to be simple if the code of the model is available. In this case, you can just rebuild the model using

```
ph = tf.Placeholder(shape=[None, None, None, 3])
predictions, loss, end_points = M.model_w_batch_nor
m(
    ph,
    segmentation
            )
```

in my example. Then create a `Saver` with `slim.get_variables_to_restore()` and restore the model from the checkpoint. This way a new graph is built which does not contain the batching operators.